# Fitting a regression discontinuity model in R with covariates using rdrobust package

Tags: r

How do I specify covariates for regression discontinuity model using 'rdrobust' package in R?

The problem is with 'covs' parameter in the code below. It is supposed to allow specifying additional covariates for the model. I have tried providing a vector of vectors from the dataset (as in the code below) and a vector of variable names but neither seem to work.

```
fm = rdrobust(datasets$CONTINUANCE,
              dataset$T,
              p=3,
              covs=c(dataset$CONTENT_LENGTH, dataset$CONTENT_SNIPPET),
              kernel='uniform',
              weights=dataset$USERS,
              bwselect='msetwo',
              vce='nn',
              nnmatch=7,
              level=95)
```

As a result, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (c <= x_min | c >= x_max) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: rdrobust
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of rdrobust (0.99.4) the covariates should be incorporated as a combined object via cbind. In the example above:

```
fm = rdrobust(datasets$CONTINUANCE,
              dataset$T,
              p=3,
              covs=cbind(dataset$CONTENT_LENGTH, dataset$CONTENT_SNIPPET),
              kernel='uniform',
              weights=dataset$USERS,
              bwselect='msetwo',
              vce='nn',
              nnmatch=7,
              level=95)
```

We will keep this in mind for the next version coming soon.
Thanks,
Sebastian.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian - very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for this package is unhelpful, unfortunately. You specify the covariates like a formula (`var1 + var2`) rather than as a vector (`c(var1, var2)`), so something like this should work:

```r
fm = rdrobust(datasets$CONTINUANCE,
              dataset$T,
              p=3,
              covs=dataset$CONTENT_LENGTH + dataset$CONTENT_SNIPPET,
              kernel='uniform',
              weights=dataset$USERS,
              bwselect='msetwo',
              vce='nn',
              nnmatch=7,
              level=95)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Maybe I drop an email to the authors of the package to update the documentation.